# Why does my reactjs project on Hostinger gives a 404 error when i refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

i have deployed reactjs project on hostinger where i  refresh the page it gives me the  error 404

i have .htaccess with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

but i doesnt work,the moment i want you to notice is that i dont see that file after i run npm run build in dist folder,i mean is it supposed to be  visible there or ?